# How to not count cell if cell contains sub-string

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula to count cells within a range `B10:B1095` which do not contain certain strings

```
=COUNTIFS(
  B10:B1095, "<>",
  B10:B1095, "<>Manual",
  B10:B1095, "<>TODO")
```

How can I add an additional condition to check if the cells in a range do not contain a specific sub-string?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what exactly you are after but you can just add as many conditions as you need like:

```
=COUNTIFS(B10:B1095, "<>",
          B10:B1095, "<>Manual",
          B10:B1095, "<>TODO",
          B10:B1095, "<>x",
          B10:B1095, "<>y",
          B10:B1095, "<>z")
```

or maybe you need this:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B10:B1095, "<>",
             B10:B1095, "<>Manual",
             B10:B1095, "<>TODO"), COUNTIFS(B10:B1095, "<>x",
                                            B10:B1095, "<>y",
                                            B10:B1095, "<>z"))
```

or this one:

```
=COUNTIFS(B10:B109; "<>";
          B10:B109; "<>Manual";
          B10:B109; "<>*TODO*")
```

Comment: "<>TODO" means cell should not contain "TODO" but what if cell contains "TODOD", then cell will be counted, so I need sub-string argument ... `<>` means not this `string`, I need, not this `sub-string`

Comment: @the_prole can you share a copy of your sheet? it would be so much faster... I know what everything in that formula means... what I do not know is what exactly do you want to accomplish. could you at least add some examples? see my updated answer

Comment: What does * TODO * do. Does it mean substring?

Comment: @the_prole it means it will search for string in the cell so if the cell consists of "TODO" or "TODODODO" it will count for it

Comment: That's exactly I meant by substring, a string inside a string, thanks